# springboot2.0 undertow1.4.x configure property 'server.undertow.accesslog.pattern' using %D print time of processing request failed

Tags: java, undertow, access-log

My Springboot version is 2.0.6 and my configuration is as follows:

```
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=%t [%I] %{i,X-Forwarded-For}: %m %U%q status:%s spent:%Dms
```

However the log is as follows

```
[08/Nov/2018:18:53:40 +0800] [XNIO-5 task-22] 27.115.62.146: GET /launcher/uCenter/setting?interval=2&settingId=5bcef714c111971540fc7bf9 status:200 spent:-ms
```

As you saw at the time of processing this request was invalid.

What would have happened?

Comment: Can you show a relevant part of your undertow-handler you use ?

Comment: I have found that when undertow has done a request, its AccessLogHandler.AccessLogReceiver will record the log with an instance of HttpServerExchange.However, the HttpServerExchange instance's property requestStartTime only has a default value -1 without being initialized.When the requestStartTime equals -1, the time of processing this request can only be null(-ms).